# Storing repositories

Tags: docker, kubernetes, repository

I am new to this. I am now having a project which is developing an application. From what I known, normally people will store it on docker hub by then creating a docker container and pass it to Kubernetes. But what we are trying to do is that we wish to store the repositories without using the docker hub. Is there a way to build something like that from scratch? Which direction should I look into?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. Before asking i'll sugest to make a research on google, please also read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You're searching for a Docker repository service.  There are a couple of cloud-hosted options besides Docker Hub, the popular public cloud providers all have their own, and you can [run your own](https://docs.docker.com/registry/).

Answer (score 0):

You can install jfrog or nexus artifact management server to create repository and store your image to that artifact management repo.

Please check this [link](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry) for more details.